# HTML Canvas fillRect fill 25% of window-height

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to learn how to use HTML's Canvas and it's properties. 
Now I'm trying to draw a ground and a sky, and I want the sky to be 75% of screens height and ground to be 25%.

This was easy using a div, and style it with CSS or JavaScript CSS Query. Now that I'm on a Canvas, I can't figure out how to set the fillRect properties...

My code:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

var skyHeight = windowHeight - (windowHeight * 0.25);
var groundHeight = windowHeight - (windowHeight * 0.75);

ctx = gameCanvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle="green";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,windowWidth,windowHeight);

ctx.fillStyle="cyan";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,windowWidth,skyHeight);
```

Also: if I try using i.e.

```
ctx.fillStyle="cyan";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,30,30);
```

This draws a perfect square on top of the green "ground"-background, but if I change to i.e.

```
ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
```

it will fill my entire height of the screen, and more than 50% of my screen-width.

According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillstyle.asp canvas fillrect are using pixels, but 200 x 200 pixels should definitely NOT fill my entire screen height. :/

Comment: Where's the part where you tell canvas what its dimensions are? Just like any other HTML element that you need to be of a specific size, you need to tell it what its `width` and `height` is, otherwise it'll just pick random values that won't be what you need them to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where's the part where you tell canvas what its dimensions are? Just like any other HTML media element that you need to be of a specific size (video, image), you need to tell it what its `width` and `height` is if you want reliably sized content (if you don't, [by convention](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-author-20120329/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element) the canvas will be sized 300 x 150px). And because we're setting the number of pixels we can draw on, this is not "purely cosmetic" like CSS, we have to do it properly:

```
var cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");

// if you didn't use <canvas width="..." height="...">, we need this:
cvs.width = 800;
cvs.height = 400;
```

And then you can do your drawing:

```
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(0,0.75*cvs.height, cvs.width,0.25*cvs.height);

ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
ctx.fillRect(0,0, cvs.width, 0.75*cvs.height);
```

See http://jsbin.com/tejiqixeji/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This is kinda embarrasing... I was working on a jQuery mobile swipe recognizing script at the same time, so I was doing: 
    
    $("#start").css("width", windowWidth);
    $("#start").css("height", windowHeight);

instead of setting the canvas-size... :/ Thanks for the remind! :P

Comment: yeah that'll just cosmetically stetch the canvas and things'll look *really* weird =)

Comment: "like any other HTML media element ..." that's completely wrong. Except `<audio>` tag (for obvious reasons), every HTML media element will get its default size set to the one of its content. But canvas as no content when created, so browsers have to default to a 300*150 rect (and not "random values" like you said in your comment on OP).

Comment: I see you're conveniently ignoring the "that you need to be of a specific size" part, which is in that sentence for a reason. If you need an image element or video element *sized to specific dimensions*, then yes: you absolutely need to specify those values. In this case the canvas needed to be the size of the window, so those values need to get fixed somewhere before things'll work as intended. Although you are entirely right in that they're not random, so I've added a link to the spec for that to the answer.